# React not working in bundle.js - How to debug?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I ran these commands:

```
1. npm install --save react
2. npm install --save react-dom
3. npm install --save--dev babel-core babel-loader babel-presetreact
```

Angular works fine and React works when using CDN in script tags. But I would like to use it through the bundle, how can I debug this?

This is how my package.json file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: what exactly the error you are getting?

Comment: No error, thats the problem.